# (Beginner Mode) Properties of Variables When Called

Tags: c++

So I'm beginning to learn C++ and came upon this example--

```
#include <iostream>

void doIt(int x)
{
    x = 3;
    int y = 4;
    std::cout << "doIt: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    std::cout << "main: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    doIt(x);
    std::cout << "main: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

--and for the sequence where doIt() is called, doit: x = 3 y = 4 is printed. Maybe there is some unknown thing I could search to better understand what happened, but essentially what I'm wondering is whether x was passed to the function as a variable or as its value (1). If it were passed as 1, wouldn't there be an error? Does this mean that the function would require an integer variable rather than a standalone integer? This program was intended to show how these variables are local, but I'm not sure how it all fits together.

Comment: Difference between pass by value and pass by reference...

Comment: I think you might need to read a good [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to understand how calling functions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an integer to your function `doIt(int x)`, the `int` you are passing will be copied. therefore anything you do to `x` inside the body of `doIt()` will be exclusive to the copy that lives in `doIt()`

notice that the name of the variable could be the same, or could be different. it makes no difference. if you are passing by VALUE, the variable content will ALWAYS be copied.

```
#include <iostream>

void doIt(int x) //x here is completely different value than in main
                 //even though they have the same name
{
    x = 3; //this variable has its own scope
    int y = 4;
    std::cout << "doIt: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
} //at the end of this function x is destroyed

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    std::cout << "main: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;

    doIt(x); //the content of variable x will be passed by value to doIt()

    std::cout << "main: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There is another way to pass parameters in C++ which is pass by reference semantics. it looks like this:

```
void doIt(int &z) //z is passed by reference, changing it will stick
//z is the SAME variable that was passed in, even if the name is different
{
    z = 3; //this will change the value that was passed in
    int y = 4;
    std::cout << "doIt: z = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;

} //z is not destroyed here, because it wasnt created in this scope

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    std::cout << "main: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl; //x is 1
    doIt(x);
    std::cout << "main: x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl; //x is 3 now
    return 0;
}
```

Pass by reference will "secretly" send your variable by its memory address, so the `int` that your function receives will actually be the SAME one that was passed in. Note that I chose the variable name z because the name of the variable in different scopes doesn't actually matter.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I do learn much better when I ask follow-up questions, but yeah I guess I probably should have read all of the answers before asking additional questions.

Comment: No, followup questions are good :) I meant you should pick a best answer so the question is solved. It awards reputation for people who take the time to explain

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not passed to functions - values are. (If we say a "variable was passed to a function", it's just short for saying the *value* of the variable was passed to the function)

When `doIt` is called, `x` and `y` in `doIt` are *brand new variables, unrelated to the ones in `main`*. The first parameter's value (which is the value of `x` in `main`, which is 1) is stored in `x`. Then, 3 is stored in `x` (by the line `x = 3;`). Then, 4 is stored in `y`. Then you print `x` and `y`, which contain the values 3 and 4.

Once `doIt` returns, `main`'s variables haven't been changed, because they're different variables (that coincidentally have the same name). So `main` prints 1 and 2 again.

Comment: If the values are what's being passed, why is there no error from 1(x) = 3?

Comment: @A.J.Hulgus Because `x` is a variable? Why's there no error from `int i = 7; i = 6;`?

Comment: `x` is a variable (both `x`es), but neither of the variables themselves are passed, only the value.

Comment: Yeah I guess that was kind of a convoluted follow-up question. I was thinking that the value being passed would replace any instance of the placeholder for parameters, which would have resulted in 1 = 3, but now it seems like a new variable is actually created which is set equal to the argument. Maybe this is right? Either way thank you!

Comment: @A.J.Hulgus Yes. `x` in `doIt` is a new variable which is set equal to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

x is passed by value but a new x is created in the method. The new x will have the value passed into the method. The new x is limited in scope to the method: a local variable.

You can assign the local x it a new value, as your code does. It will not affect the variable in the calling method.

Comment: Does this mean that passing x is like putting doIt((int x created for function) = (x or whatever value is being passed))?

Comment: yes. It all happens automagically for you. The local variable with the same name is created and destroyed for you.

Answer (score 0):

When a function takes an plain argument (such as `int x`) the compiler will pass the VALUE to the called function (aka "callee"). Inside the callee, that value is stored in a local variable [1], so when you update it by saying `x = 3`, the COPY inside the function is updated, not the original value in the caller.

This is a good thing, because it means you can pass a value to a function wihtout having to KNOW if the function changes it or not.

If you want to modify the value of an input variable, it needs to be a reference, `void doIt(int &x)` - in which case the compiler will pass the actual variable by reference, such that you can modify it [technically, this means passing the address of the variable, rather than it's content, and then relevant code in the callee to handle the difference].

[1] Yes, technically, that copy is most often done at the caller code.

Comment: Thanks! Slightly unrelated, but I couldn't help but notice how amazingly fast these answers come. Do people just go to this website and answer questions for fun?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Why else do you think people answer questions? Nobody here is being paid specifically to answer questions (or if they are, I'd like to know how you get paid! ;) )

Comment: I also hang around here because I get to learn from other people's answers.